# Laravel Relationship problems: Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I must be missing something obvious. I've got a Invoice_detail Model:

```
class Invoice_detail extends Eloquent {

public function products()
{
    $this->belongsTo('Product');

}
}
```

A Product Model:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

public function invoiceDetails()
{
    $this->hasMany('Invoice_detail');
}
}
```

but when I try to use this:

```
Route::get('/', function(){

  $detail =  Invoice_detail::whereId(27)->first();

  return $detail->products;
});
```

I get: `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`

What am I missing here?

Comment: BTW, `Invoice_detail::whereId(27)->first();` == `Invoice_detail::find(27);`

Comment: @JosephSilber A lot cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep - your relationship methods should have returns on them:

```
public function invoiceDetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Invoice_detail');
}
```

Comment: You can't imagine the shame I feel right now. I spent over an hour staring at it, renaming it, changing the camelCasing, trying underscores. This is face palm on an epic level. Thank you.